# Query the XMl files using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, xml, xquery

Here there is an XML file [click here to see the XML file](http://data.crea.ca/Search.svc/Search?Format=Standard-XML&SearchType=Property&Class=Property&QueryType=DMQL2&Culture=en-CA&Query=%28LastUpdated=2014-05-08T22:00:17Z%29)

I'm completely new to this,I want to get the properties that satisfy the below conditions:

```
  Where city=Toronto(present in address node) and price is > 13000 and BathroomTotal>2(present in Building node)
```

Using php or javascript which is good to query such a huge file with speed.
How can I get the properties with condition I mentioned.

Note: Change the values I given in where condition, you can put any city name or any price value

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXML:www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php OR
PCRE (for efficiency )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query client-side, an XQuery option is [XQuery in the Browser](http://www.xqib.org).